# How `String["fromCharCode"]` acts like `String.fromCharCode()` in javascript?

Tags: javascript

*Search engine will ignore the `[ ] "`, so I can't get the answer.*
I took a test and find out they resulted the same, but I'm a js rookie and I don't know how they equals to each other.

Answer (score 1):

`fromCharCode` 'lives' as a static method of the `String` Object. Such a method has a key and a value, visualised: `{fromCharCode: function() {...}}`. You can retrieve (access) the method using it's *key* directly `String.fromCharCode` or 'bracket' style `String['fromCharCode']`. This is true for all Objects.

The bracket notation may be usefull when the key contains special characters, see snippet.

[See also](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)

```js
const someObj = {
  dotNotation: 'hello world',
  'non dot Notation': 'hello world you too',
};

console.log(someObj.dotNotation);
// the last property can not be retrieved with dot notation
// console.log(someObj.non dot Notation);
// so
console.log(someObj['non dot Notation']);
```

Comment: "static method of a `String` Object" -> "static method of the `String` Object". Otherwise it might confuse readers who don't know what "static" means.